# How to use menu items using SASS

Tags: sass

I am creating menu items with their class name as l1, l2 respectively and want to provide different background colors to each item. To get desired background color for each item in CSS file I have to write my code like this:

```
.menu ul li.l1 {
  background: red;
}
.menu ul li.l2 {
  background: green;
}
```

in Sass i am trying to use nesting property and write my code like this:

```
.menu {
  some properties
  ul li {
    some properties
    .l1 {
      background: red;
    }
  }
}
```

On writing above mentioned code I am getting following CSS as output:

```
.menu ul li .l1 {
  background: red;
}
```

This is not setting my desired background.

Wow can I access my menu items using SASS?

Comment: have to agree with @cimmanon ... the `&` before `.l1` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.l1` is not declared properly.

```
.menu {

  ul li {

    &.l1 {
      background: red;
    }
  }
}
```